# Completing external HTTP call in ExpressJS middleware before response is rendered

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to use Express middleware for a login request. Default route provides an external url that redirects to `/login?code={login-code}`, which makes an external HTTP request to get `user_id` and `access_token`. Retrieving these information means user is logged in, so page should be redirected to `/home`. However, I am not able to implement this scenario with the code below.

I think the problem is that request (to `/login`) is completed and response is rendered already when external HTTP request is completed and body is decoded. How can I resolve this issue?

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Index', login: login_url });
});

app.get('/login', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('CODE: ' + req.query.code);

  https.get(getAuthOptions(req.query.code), function(httpRes) {
    var data = '';
    httpRes.on('data', function(chunk) {
      data += chunk;
    });
    httpRes.on('end', function() {
      var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
      req.session.user = {
        user_id: jsonData['user_id'],
        access_token: jsonData['access_token']
      };

      if (req.session.user) {
        next('route');
      }
    });
  }).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
  });

  res.render('index', { title: 'Login' });
});

app.get('/home', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.session.user);
  res.render('index', { title: 'Home' });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, `res.render` is executed before external request is processed.

Long answer:
Ideally, there should be a `post` handler for `login` since it will most probably be mutating your app state. 
In `.get('/login')` just render the page
Create `.post('/login')` and make the `https.get` call and redirect to `/home` on `httpRes.on('end'`.

Bonus,use https://www.npmjs.com/package/request to make the external calls.